# Getting Windows 2012R2 ISO in Azure

Tags: windows, azure, upgrade

We have a legacy app that runs on Win 2012R2 VM in Azure.  We had to build a new environment for testing and accidently the sysadmin created a VM with Win 2012(not R2).  Now we have asked them to upgrade and apparently they don't have the ISO and after raising a ticket with Microsoft they also are not providing it as it is so close to end of life.  We will have the env around for two more years at least and going to use the extended security update available in Azure.

It feels odd to me that MS wont provide the ISO for an OS which is currently within support, is available to create new VM's with in Azure marketplace and has extended security update until 2026.
How do we obtain an ISO? Is there a way to get ISO from a VM template in Azure?
I can see it on [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/download-windows-server-2012-r2) site, looks like eval, can we use that for upgrade

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom image using Hyper-V and then upload this to Microsoft Azure. If you then deploy a virtual machine into Azure from the uploaded custom image, then you can create a generalised image in Azure and deploy as many as you like from the generalised disk. For further information, see the two links below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/prepare-for-upload-vhd-image.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/generalize